How can I optimize Elliott Wave detection in large cryptocurrency datasets?
I am working on a Python program that identifies Elliott Wave patterns in cryptocurrency market data. The current implementation uses nested loops and exhaustive searches, which makes it computationally expensive for large datasets.
Here is my code:
from IPython import get_ipython
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math
import time

from matplotlib import rc
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import rcParams
from scipy import signal

import os
import datetime as dt
import seaborn as sns

# PLOTTING SETUP
get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
get_ipython().run_line_magic('config', "InlineBackend.figure_format='retina'")
register_matplotlib_converters()
sns.set(style='whitegrid', palette='muted', font_scale=1.5)
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 22, 10

# COMMODITY
dateTimeObj = dt.datetime.now()
today = dateTimeObj.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

symbol = "BTC-USD"
date = today

def getData():
    df = pd.read_csv("bitcoin_data.csv")

    # Preprocess the data
    # 1. Remove the "Change %" column
    df.drop(columns=['Change %'], inplace=True)

    # 2. Convert the 'Date' column to datetime format
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

    # 3. Rename the 'Price' column to 'Close'
    df.rename(columns={'Price': 'Close'}, inplace=True)

    # 5. Fill any null values with zero
    df.fillna(0, inplace=True)

    # Convert 'Vol.' column to numeric values
    df['Vol.'] = df['Vol.'].astype(str).str.replace('K', '')
    df['Vol.'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Vol.'], errors='coerce')
    df['Vol.'] = df['Vol.'].fillna(0) * 1000

    # Convert the other columns to numeric
    for col in ['Close', 'Open', 'High', 'Low']:
        df[col] = df[col].replace({',': ''}, regex=True).astype(float)

    return df

# def minmaxTwoMeasures(df, measureMin, measureMax, column, order=3):
#     # Use Low values for minima and High values for maxima
#     df['DateTmp'] = df.index
#     x = np.array(df["DateTmp"].values)

#     # Use Low values for finding minima
#     y1 = np.array(df["Low"].values)
#     # Use High values for finding maxima
#     y2 = np.array(df["High"].values)

#     sortId = np.argsort(x)
#     x = x[sortId]
#     y1 = y1[sortId]
#     y2 = y2[sortId]

#     df[column] = 0

#     # Find maxima using High values
#     maxm = signal.argrelextrema(y2, np.greater, order=order)
#     # Find minima using Low values
#     minm = signal.argrelextrema(y1, np.less, order=order)

#     for elem in maxm[0]:
#         df.iloc[elem, df.columns.get_loc(column)] = 1
#     for elem in minm[0]:
#         df.iloc[elem, df.columns.get_loc(column)] = -1

#     return df.drop(columns=['DateTmp'])

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def minmaxTwoMeasures(df):
    """
    Process the DataFrame to identify peaks using Highs and troughs using Lows.
    Adds a 'FlowMinMax' column where:
    - 1 represents peaks (Highs),
    - -1 represents troughs (Lows),
    - 0 represents all other points.

    Returns a DataFrame with columns: Date, Open, High, Close, Low, FlowMinMax.
    """
    # Ensure 'Date' is in datetime format
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

    # Ensure numeric columns are converted properly
    for col in ['Open', 'High', 'Close', 'Low']:
        df[col] = df[col].replace({',': ''}, regex=True).astype(float)

    # Process Peaks and Troughs
    high_data = df['High'].values
    low_data = df['Low'].values

    # Identify Peaks from High values
    doublediff_high = np.diff(np.sign(np.diff(high_data)))
    high_peak_locations = np.where(doublediff_high == -2)[0] + 1

    # Identify Troughs from Low values
    doublediff_low = np.diff(np.sign(np.diff(-1 * low_data)))
    low_trough_locations = np.where(doublediff_low == -2)[0] + 1

    # Add FlowMinMax column to the DataFrame
    df['FlowMinMax'] = 0  # Initialize with 0s
    df.loc[df.index[high_peak_locations], 'FlowMinMax'] = 1  # Assign 1 for peaks
    df.loc[df.index[low_trough_locations], 'FlowMinMax'] = -1  # Assign -1 for troughs

    # Return the required columns
    return df[['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Close', 'Low', 'FlowMinMax']]

def isMin(df,i):
    return df["FlowMinMax"].iat[i] == -1

def isMax(df,i):
    return df["FlowMinMax"].iat[i] == 1

def distance(x1,y1,x2,y2):
     dist = math.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)
     return dist

def validate_wave_sequence(df, value, i0, i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, ia, ib, ic, wave_type='up'):
    """
    Modified to use High/Low values for validation
    """
    try:
        if wave_type == 'up':
            # Wave 1 (Points 0-1)
            for i in range(i0, i1 + 1):
                if df['Low'].iloc[i] < df['Low'].iloc[i0]:  # Use Low for troughs
                    return False
                if df['High'].iloc[i] > df['High'].iloc[i1]:  # Use High for peaks
                    return False

            # Wave 2 (Points 1-2)
            for i in range(i1, i2 + 1):
                if df['High'].iloc[i] > df['High'].iloc[i1]:
                    return False
                if df['Low'].iloc[i] < df['Low'].iloc[i2]:
                    return False

            # Wave 3 (Points 2-3)
            for i in range(i2, i3 + 1):
                if df['Low'].iloc[i] < df['Low'].iloc[i2]:
                    return False
                if df['High'].iloc[i] > df['High'].iloc[i3]:
                    return False

            # Wave 4 (Points 3-4)
            for i in range(i3, i4 + 1):
                if df['High'].iloc[i] > df['High'].iloc[i3]:
                    return False
                if df['Low'].iloc[i] < df['Low'].iloc[i4]:
                    return False

            # Wave 5 (Points 4-5)
            for i in range(i4, i5 + 1):
                if df['Low'].iloc[i] < df['Low'].iloc[i4]:
                    return False
                if df['High'].iloc[i] > df['High'].iloc[i5]:
                    return False

            # Corrective Waves (A-B-C)
            if ia is not None and ib is not None and ic is not None:
                # Wave A (Points 5-ia)
                for i in range(i5, ia + 1):
                    if df['High'].iloc[i] > df['High'].iloc[i5]:
                        return False
                    if df['Low'].iloc[i] < df['Low'].iloc[ia]:
                        return False

                # Wave B (Points ia-ib)
                for i in range(ia, ib + 1):
                    if df['Low'].iloc[i] < df['Low'].iloc[ia]:
                        return False
                    if df['High'].iloc[i] > df['High'].iloc[ib]:
                        return False

                # Wave C (Points ib-ic)
                for i in range(ib, ic + 1):
                    if df['High'].iloc[i] > df['High'].iloc[ib]:
                        return False
                    if df['Low'].iloc[i] < df['Low'].iloc[ic]:
                        return False

        else:  # downtrend
            # Similar modifications for downtrend using High/Low values
            # Wave 1 (Points 0-1)
            for i in range(i0, i1 + 1):
                if df['High'].iloc[i] > df['High'].iloc[i0]:
                    return False
                if df['Low'].iloc[i] < df['Low'].iloc[i1]:
                    return False

            # Wave 2 (Points 1-2)
            for i in range(i1, i2 + 1):
                if df['Low'].iloc[i] < df['Low'].iloc[i1]:
                    return False
                if df['High'].iloc[i] > df['High'].iloc[i2]:
                    return False

            # Wave 3 (Points 2-3)
            for i in range(i2, i3 + 1):
                if df['High'].iloc[i] > df['High'].iloc[i2]:
                    return False
                if df['Low'].iloc[i] < df['Low'].iloc[i3]:
                    return False

            # Wave 4 (Points 3-4)
            for i in range(i3, i4 + 1):
                if df['Low'].iloc[i] < df['Low'].iloc[i3]:
                    return False
                if df['High'].iloc[i] > df['High'].iloc[i4]:
                    return False

            # Wave 5 (Points 4-5)
            for i in range(i4, i5 + 1):
                if df['High'].iloc[i] > df['High'].iloc[i4]:
                    return False
                if df['Low'].iloc[i] < df['Low'].iloc[i5]:
                    return False

            # Corrective Waves (A-B-C)
            if ia is not None and ib is not None and ic is not None:
                # Wave A (Points 5-ia)
                for i in range(i5, ia + 1):
                    if df['Low'].iloc[i] < df['Low'].iloc[i5]:
                        return False
                    if df['High'].iloc[i] > df['High'].iloc[ia]:
                        return False

                # Wave B (Points ia-ib)
                for i in range(ia, ib + 1):
                    if df['High'].iloc[i] > df['High'].iloc[ia]:
                        return False
                    if df['Low'].iloc[i] < df['Low'].iloc[ib]:
                        return False

                # Wave C (Points ib-ic)
                for i in range(ib, ic + 1):
                    if df['Low'].iloc[i] < df['Low'].iloc[ib]:
                        return False
                    if df['High'].iloc[i] > df['High'].iloc[ic]:
                        return False

        return True
    except IndexError:
        return False

def isElliottWave(df, value, i0, i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, ia, ib, ic, wave_type='up'):
    """
    Check if the given sequence forms an Elliott Wave pattern with comprehensive validation
    """
    try:
        # First validate the sequence integrity with comprehensive rules
        if not validate_wave_sequence(df, value, i0, i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, ia, ib, ic, wave_type):
            return None

        # Check min and max points based on wave type
        if wave_type == 'up':
            # For uptrend
            if (df['FlowMinMax'].iloc[i0] != -1 or df['FlowMinMax'].iloc[i2] != -1 or
                df['FlowMinMax'].iloc[i4] != -1 or df['FlowMinMax'].iloc[ia] != -1 or
                df['FlowMinMax'].iloc[ic] != -1):
                return None

            if (df['FlowMinMax'].iloc[i1] != 1 or df['FlowMinMax'].iloc[i3] != 1 or
                df['FlowMinMax'].iloc[i5] != 1 or df['FlowMinMax'].iloc[ib] != 1):
                return None
        else:
            # For downtrend
            if (df['FlowMinMax'].iloc[i0] != 1 or df['FlowMinMax'].iloc[i2] != 1 or
                df['FlowMinMax'].iloc[i4] != 1 or df['FlowMinMax'].iloc[ia] != 1 or
                df['FlowMinMax'].iloc[ic] != 1):
                return None

            if (df['FlowMinMax'].iloc[i1] != -1 or df['FlowMinMax'].iloc[i3] != -1 or
                df['FlowMinMax'].iloc[i5] != -1 or df['FlowMinMax'].iloc[ib] != -1):
                return None

        # Check wave conditions based on trend type
        if wave_type == 'up':
            # Check if i5 is the top
            if not (df[value].iloc[i5] > df[value].iloc[i1] and
                    df[value].iloc[i5] > df[value].iloc[i2] and
                    df[value].iloc[i5] > df[value].iloc[i3] and
                    df[value].iloc[i5] > df[value].iloc[i4]):
                return None

            conditions = [
                df[value].iloc[i1] > df[value].iloc[i0],
                df[value].iloc[i1] > df[value].iloc[i2],
                df[value].iloc[i2] > df[value].iloc[i0],
                df[value].iloc[i3] > df[value].iloc[i2],
                df[value].iloc[i3] > df[value].iloc[i4],
                df[value].iloc[i4] > df[value].iloc[i2],
                df[value].iloc[i4] > df[value].iloc[i1],
                df[value].iloc[i5] > df[value].iloc[i4],
                df[value].iloc[i5] > df[value].iloc[i3]
            ]
        else:
            # Check if i5 is the bottom
            if not (df[value].iloc[i5] < df[value].iloc[i1] and
                    df[value].iloc[i5] < df[value].iloc[i2] and
                    df[value].iloc[i5] < df[value].iloc[i3] and
                    df[value].iloc[i5] < df[value].iloc[i4]):
                return None

            conditions = [
                df[value].iloc[i1] < df[value].iloc[i0],
                df[value].iloc[i1] < df[value].iloc[i2],
                df[value].iloc[i2] < df[value].iloc[i0],
                df[value].iloc[i3] < df[value].iloc[i2],
                df[value].iloc[i3] < df[value].iloc[i4],
                df[value].iloc[i4] < df[value].iloc[i2],
                df[value].iloc[i4] < df[value].iloc[i1],
                df[value].iloc[i5] < df[value].iloc[i4],
                df[value].iloc[i5] < df[value].iloc[i3]
            ]

        if not all(conditions):
            return None

        # Calculate wave lengths
        w1_len = distance(i0, df[value].iloc[i0], i1, df[value].iloc[i1])
        w3_len = distance(i2, df[value].iloc[i2], i3, df[value].iloc[i3])
        w5_len = distance(i4, df[value].iloc[i4], i5, df[value].iloc[i5])

        if w3_len < w1_len and w3_len < w5_len:
            return None

        # Check ABC wave conditions based on trend type
        if wave_type == 'up':
            abc_conditions = [
                df[value].iloc[i5] > df[value].iloc[ia],
                df[value].iloc[i5] > df[value].iloc[ib],
                df[value].iloc[i5] > df[value].iloc[ic],
                df[value].iloc[ib] > df[value].iloc[ia],
                df[value].iloc[ia] > df[value].iloc[ic],
                df[value].iloc[ib] > df[value].iloc[ic]
            ]
        else:
            abc_conditions = [
                df[value].iloc[i5] < df[value].iloc[ia],
                df[value].iloc[i5] < df[value].iloc[ib],
                df[value].iloc[i5] < df[value].iloc[ic],
                df[value].iloc[ib] < df[value].iloc[ia],
                df[value].iloc[ia] < df[value].iloc[ic],
                df[value].iloc[ib] < df[value].iloc[ic]
            ]

        if all(abc_conditions):
            return [i0, i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, ia, ib, ic]

        return [i0, i1, i2, i3, i4, i5]

    except IndexError:
        return None


def ElliottWaveDiscovery(df, measure, wave_type='up'):
    """Discover Elliott Wave patterns in the data for both uptrend and downtrend"""
    print(f"Starting Elliott Wave Discovery for {wave_type}trend...")
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

    def minRange(df, start, end):
        return [i for i in range(start, end) if i < len(df) and df['FlowMinMax'].iloc[i] == -1]

    def maxRange(df, start, end):
        return [i for i in range(start, end) if i < len(df) and df['FlowMinMax'].iloc[i] == 1]

    execution_count = 0
    start_time = time.time()
    waves = []

    # For uptrend, start with minima; for downtrend, start with maxima
    initial_points = minRange(df, 0, len(df)) if wave_type == 'up' else maxRange(df, 0, len(df))
    print(f"Number of {'minimum' if wave_type == 'up' else 'maximum'} points: {len(initial_points)}")

    for i0 in initial_points:
        next_points_1 = maxRange(df, i0+1, len(df)) if wave_type == 'up' else minRange(df, i0+1, len(df))
        for i1 in next_points_1:
            next_points_2 = minRange(df, i1+1, len(df)) if wave_type == 'up' else maxRange(df, i1+1, len(df))
            for i2 in next_points_2:
                next_points_3 = maxRange(df, i2+1, len(df)) if wave_type == 'up' else minRange(df, i2+1, len(df))
                for i3 in next_points_3:
                    next_points_4 = minRange(df, i3+1, len(df)) if wave_type == 'up' else maxRange(df, i3+1, len(df))
                    for i4 in next_points_4:
                        next_points_5 = maxRange(df, i4+1, len(df)) if wave_type == 'up' else minRange(df, i4+1, len(df))
                        for i5 in next_points_5:
                            # Check wave direction condition
                            condition = (df[measure].iloc[i5] > df[measure].iloc[i1] and
                                      df[measure].iloc[i5] > df[measure].iloc[i2] and
                                      df[measure].iloc[i5] > df[measure].iloc[i3] and
                                      df[measure].iloc[i5] > df[measure].iloc[i4]) if wave_type == 'up' else (
                                      df[measure].iloc[i5] < df[measure].iloc[i1] and
                                      df[measure].iloc[i5] < df[measure].iloc[i2] and
                                      df[measure].iloc[i5] < df[measure].iloc[i3] and
                                      df[measure].iloc[i5] < df[measure].iloc[i4])

                            if condition:
                                next_points_a = minRange(df, i5+1, len(df)) if wave_type == 'up' else maxRange(df, i5+1, len(df))
                                for ia in next_points_a:
                                    next_points_b = maxRange(df, ia+1, len(df)) if wave_type == 'up' else minRange(df, ia+1, len(df))
                                    for ib in next_points_b:
                                        next_points_c = minRange(df, ib+1, len(df)) if wave_type == 'up' else maxRange(df, ib+1, len(df))
                                        for ic in next_points_c:
                                            wave = isElliottWave(df, measure, i0,i1,i2,i3,i4,i5,ia,ib,ic, wave_type)
                                            execution_count += 1
                                            if wave is not None and wave not in waves:
                                                print(f"Found {wave_type}trend wave: {wave}")
                                                waves.append(wave)
                                                wave_values = [df[measure].iat[idx] for idx in wave]
                                                print(f"Wave Values: {wave_values}")

                                                # Plotting the wave
                                                plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
                                                plt.plot(df[measure], label="Full Dataset", color='blue', alpha=0.5)
                                                plt.plot(wave, wave_values, marker='o', label=f"Detected {wave_type}trend Wave", color='red')
                                                plt.title(f"Elliott Wave Detection - {wave_type}trend")
                                                plt.xlabel("Index")
                                                plt.ylabel(measure)
                                                plt.legend()
                                                plt.grid(True)
                                                plt.show()

    end_time = time.time()
    print(f"Total iterations: {execution_count}")
    print(f"Total time taken: {end_time - start_time:.2f} seconds")
    print(f"Total {wave_type}trend waves found: {len(waves)}")

    return waves


def draw_wave(df, df_waves, w=None):
    """
    Draw peaks and troughs of the wave pattern

    Parameters:
    df: Original dataframe with price data
    df_waves: Dataframe containing only the wave points
    w: List of indices representing specific wave points (optional)
    """
    plt.figure(figsize=(15, 7))

    # If no specific wave points provided, use all peaks and troughs
    if w is None:
        # Convert df_waves to a list of indices where FlowMinMax is not 0
        w = list(range(len(df_waves)))

    if len(w) > 0:
        wave_points_y = []
        wave_points_x = []

        # Get points for plotting
        for i in range(len(df_waves)):
            # Determine if it's a peak or trough
            if df_waves['FlowMinMax'].iloc[i] != 0:  # If it's either a peak or trough
                if df_waves['FlowMinMax'].iloc[i] == 1:  # Peak
                    wave_points_y.append(df_waves['High'].iloc[i])
                else:  # Trough
                    wave_points_y.append(df_waves['Low'].iloc[i])
                wave_points_x.append(i)  # Use simple index for x-axis

        if len(wave_points_x) > 0:  # Only plot if we have points
            # Plot wave connections
            plt.plot(wave_points_x, wave_points_y, 'r-', linewidth=2, label='Price Movement')

            # Plot peaks and troughs with different markers
            for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(wave_points_x, wave_points_y)):
                if df_waves['FlowMinMax'].iloc[x] == 1:  # Peak
                    plt.plot(x, y, 'r^', markersize=10, label='Peak' if i == 0 else "")
                else:  # Trough
                    plt.plot(x, y, 'rv', markersize=10, label='Trough' if i == 0 else "")

                # Add point labels
                plt.annotate(f'P{i}', (x, y), xytext=(5, 5),
                            textcoords='offset points', color='red')

    plt.title("Market Peaks and Troughs")
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

# select the waves the best fit the chart
def filterWaveSet(waves, min_len=6, max_len=6, extremes=True):

    result = []
    for w in waves:
        l = len(w)
        if min_len <= l and l <= max_len:
            result.append(w)

    if not extremes:
        return result

    # find the max
    max = 0
    for w in result:
        if w[len(w)-1] >= max:
            max = w[len(w)-1]

    #  filter the max
    result2 = []
    for w in result:
        if w[len(w)-1] == max:
            result2.append(w)

    print("result2")
    print(result2)

    # find the min
    min = max
    for w in result2:
        if w[0] <= min:
            min = w[0]

    #  filter the min
    result = []
    for w in result2:
        if w[0] == min:
            result.append(w)

    return result


# %%
import math

# given one line defined with two points
def line(wa,wb, x):
    x1 = wa[0]
    y1 = wa[1]
    x2 = wb[0]
    y2 = wb[1]
    y = ((y2-y1)/(x2-x1))*(x-x1) + y1
    return y


def elliottWaveLinearRegressionError(df_waves, w, value):
    diffquad = 0
    for i in range(1,len(w)):
        wa = [ w[i-1], df_waves[value].iat[w[i-1]] ]
        wb = [ w[i  ], df_waves[value].iat[w[i  ]] ]
        # for each line, we calculate the average squared error

        for xindex in range(wa[0],wb[0]):
            yindex = df_waves[value].iat[xindex]
            yline = line(wa,wb, xindex)

            diffquad += (yindex-yline) ** 2

    return math.sqrt(diffquad)/(w[len(w)-1]-w[0])

def findBestFitWave(df,value,waves):

    avg = np.Inf
    # avg = 0
    df_waves = df[[value,"FlowMinMax"]]
    result = []
    for w in waves:
        # for each wave, we generate the lines
        tmp = elliottWaveLinearRegressionError(df_waves, w, value)

        if tmp < avg:
            # print(averages)
            # print(w,tmp)
            avg = tmp
            result = w
    return result

def buildWaveChainSet(waves, startwith=9):

    def addList(list, wavelist):
        k = 0
        for w in wavelist:
            k += len(w)
        key = str(k)
        if not key in list:
            list[key] = []
        list[key].append(wavelist)
        print(wavelist)
        return list


    print("chainsets")
    list = {}
    for w1 in [wave for wave in waves if len(wave) == startwith]:
        wavelist = [w1]
        if len(w1) == 9:
            for w2 in waves:
                if (len(w2) <= len(w1)):
                    if w1[len(w1)-1] == w2[0]:
                        wavelist.append(w2)
                        addList(list, wavelist.copy())
                        wavelist.pop(-1)
        else:
            # if w1 is not complete, i can't attach another wave
            addList(list, wavelist)
    return list

if date is None:
    date = dt.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

df_source = getData()

# the dataset
df_source["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df_source["Date"], infer_datetime_format=True)
df_source.set_index("Date")

def ElliottWaveFindPattern(df_source, granularity, dateStart, dateEnd, extremes=True):
    mask = (dateStart <= df_source.Date) & (df_source.Date <= dateEnd)
    df = df_source.loc[mask]

    # Use High/Low values for finding peaks and troughs
    # FlowMinMax = minmaxTwoMeasures(df, "Low", "High", "FlowMinMax", granularity)
    FlowMinMax = minmaxTwoMeasures(df)
    df = FlowMinMax
    df_samples = df.loc[df['FlowMinMax'] != 0]

    print(f"Total data points: {len(df)}")
    print(f"Number of peaks and troughs: {len(df_samples)}")
    print("\nFirst few peaks and troughs:")
    print(df_samples.head())

    # Draw the wave
    draw_wave(df, df, None)

    print("Starting analysis...")
    # Find uptrend waves using High/Low values
    uptrend_waves = ElliottWaveDiscovery(df_samples[["High", "Low", "FlowMinMax"]], "High", 'up')
    filtered_uptrend_waves = filterWaveSet(uptrend_waves, 5, 9, extremes=extremes)
    print("Uptrend waves:", filtered_uptrend_waves)

    # Find downtrend waves using High/Low values
    downtrend_waves = ElliottWaveDiscovery(df_samples[["High", "Low", "FlowMinMax"]], "Low", 'down')
    filtered_downtrend_waves = filterWaveSet(downtrend_waves, 5, 9, extremes=extremes)
    print("Downtrend waves:", filtered_downtrend_waves)

    return filtered_uptrend_waves, filtered_downtrend_waves

ElliottWaveFindPattern(df_source, 7, "2020-01-01", "2020-03-31", extremes=False)

The nested loops make this approach infeasible for large datasets.
